# jsf navigation question

Tags: jsf

I have a JSF2 project with a "view user" page that reads the currently selected user from a session bean; userHandler.selectedUser.

The page is intended to be visited by navigating with links in the app.

However, if the user attempts to hit the "view user" page directly by this URL ...

http://localhost:8080/webapp/userView.jsf

... they see the page with no data on it (because there's no selected user in the userHandler).

I think what I'd like to do is redirect the user to the main page of the app if they try to hit it directly like that.  What is a simple and elegant way of handling this problem?

Thanks,
Rob

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'd like to hook on the `preRenderView` event and then send a redirect when this is the case.

```
<f:metadata>
    <f:event type="preRenderView" listener="#{bean.preRenderView}" />
</f:metadata>
```

with

```
public void preRenderView() throws IOException {
    if (userHandler.getSelectedUser() == null) {
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().redirect("home.jsf");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A way to avoid this problem from the start is to have pages that you don't want to be accessed directly via URL into the `WEB-INF` folder of your project.
This way, your pages aren't accessible directly via URL.

[image]

Comment: No, this is not a solution for the problem in the question. It is a solution to prevent user seeing the jsf page source and thatbis different (and existing)  Q/A https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10572458/how-do-i-protect-jsf-2-0-facelets-against-direct-access