# Using Navigation in JSF

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

**Framework: JSF 2.0.**

**My problem**: I have a page, called login.xhtml. Whenever someone view that page, it invoked a filter, called Authentication filter. The filter will check, if user already loged in, it will be redirected to default based on user's role (for example: Admin will go to "admin/admin.xhtml", student will be redirected to "user/user.xhtml").

**My solution:** Using the **JSF Navigation**

**My config:**

***faces-config.xml***

```
<navigation-rule>
    <from-view-id>*</from-view-id>
    <navigation-case>
        <from-outcome>AD</from-outcome>            
        <to-view-id>/admin/admin.xhtml</to-view-id>
    </navigation-case>
    <navigation-case>
        <from-outcome>US</from-outcome>            
        <to-view-id>/user/user.xhtml</to-view-id>
    </navigation-case>
</navigation-rule>
```

***The redirection using navigation:***

```
public static void redirectUsingNavigation(String from, String outCome) {
    FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    facesContext.getApplication().getNavigationHandler().handleNavigation(facesContext, from, outCome);
}
```

**My question:**

1. When i run the **redirectUsingNavigation("*","AD")** or **redirectUsingNavigation(null,"AD")**, it does **not redirect** me to **admin.xhtml** (i'm still on login.xhtml). How to fix this?
2. Any framework support me on this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That code is not redirecting at all. It's just forwarding the request. It's just using the same request object for a different target page). A real redirect instructs the browser to send a new request on the given `Location` header. You see this change being reflected back in browser address bar.

You need to *either* add `faces-redirect=true` parameter to the outcome to trigger the redirect (this is particularly useful if you're using implicit navigation instead of verbose navigation cases):

```
navigationHandler.handleNavigation(facesContext, from, outCome + "?faces-redirect=true")
```

*Or* add `<redirect/>` to the navigation cases if you want them to always take place:

```html
<navigation-rule>
    <from-view-id>*</from-view-id>
    <navigation-case>
        <from-outcome>AD</from-outcome>            
        <to-view-id>/admin/admin.xhtml</to-view-id>
        <redirect/>
    </navigation-case>
    <navigation-case>
        <from-outcome>US</from-outcome>            
        <to-view-id>/user/user.xhtml</to-view-id>
        <redirect/>
    </navigation-case>
</navigation-rule>
```

Last but not least, you need to ensure that `handleNavigation()` is called **before** the response is committed, otherwise it won't work at all and your server logs would be littered with `IllegalStateException: response already committed` errors. You can make use of `<f:event type="preRenderView">` to invoke a bean action before the response is committed.

#### See also:

- [jsf navigation question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6207433/jsf-navigation-question)
- [Hit a bean method and redirect on a GET request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7488211/jsf-how-to-hit-a-bean-method-and-redirect-based-on-a-get-variable)