# How do I protect JSF 2.0 facelets against direct access?

Tags: java, jsf, facelets

I have found one idea [here](http://old.nabble.com/how-to-prevent-direct-access-to-jsf-pages--td16807991.html), putting files under /WEB-INF is a way to block direct access:

> With Facelets, one can also put XHTML files under the /WEB-INF, if
>   they are templates or included files (same restrictions as with JSP
>   essentially).

The page also presents a solution based on Java EE security, which allows direct XHTML access only to members of a specific user group.

```
<security-constraint>
    <display-name>Restrict XHTML Documents</display-name>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>XHTML</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <description>Only let 'developer's access XHTML pages</description>
        <role-name>developer</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>
```

Would you recommend one of these solutions, or are both generally used?

Comment: In the first case, the end user will never have access to the page. While in the second case, **authorized** users will have access to the page. Their purpose is different. If your facelets are templates go with the first, otherwise second.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Putting in the `/WEB-INF` folder is only applicable for template files, include files and tag files which should **never** be accessed directly and standalone by URL, also not by a valid mapping.

The security constraint is only applicable for public files when you haven't mapped the `FacesServlet` on `*.xhtml`. If you have for example mapped it on `*.jsf` then you can open public resources by `foo.jsf` URLs, but one could retrieve the raw XHTML source code by just changing the extension to `foo.xhtml`. That security constraint prevents this.

But better is to just map the `FacesServlet` on `*.xhtml` directly. This way you don't need that security constraint anymore. However, template/include/tag files should still be placed in `/WEB-INF` folder. To get the general idea, you may find the source of the [OmniFaces showcase project](https://github.com/omnifaces/showcase) helpful (see `WEB-INF` [here](https://github.com/omnifaces/showcase/tree/master/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF)).

#### See also:

- [Which XHTML files do I need to put in /WEB-INF and which not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9031811/which-xhtml-files-do-i-need-to-put-in-web-inf-and-which-not)
- [JSF files inside WEB-INF directory, how do I access them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512234/jsf-files-inside-web-inf-directory-model-2-pattern)

Comment: What about fragments packaged in a jar? If i drop them in /META-INF/resources the users can access the raw fragments...

Answer (score 1):

It is extremely plausible that .xhtml can be placed under and served from the web information folder.

I would instead of relying on decorative programming such as putting rules into web.xml, look into security solution such as JSecurity to provide JAAS for my application.